# How to include xml file from other project in gitlab ci pipeline?

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a project `/templates` where I want to add a common `ci_settings.xml` that sets some defaults for `maven` commands.

I then want to reuse this template in another project:

`.gitlab_ci.yml`:

```
image: maven:3.8.4-eclipse-temurin-11

include:
  project: 'all/templates'
  ref: master
  file:
    - 'ci_settings.xml'

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script: mvn deploy -s ci_settings.xml
```

Result:

```
Found errors in your .gitlab-ci.yml:
    Included file `ci_settings.xml` does not have YAML extension!
```

How can I actually make use of this external file, if not via `include`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `include` only with yml files. But you can clone the `/templates` project in your pipeline via `CI_JOB_TOKEN` and use it this way. As you don't need the commit history here you can set the depth to 1.

```
image: maven:3.8.4-eclipse-temurin-11

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - git clone --depth 1 https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@your_path_to_templates_project.git templates
    - mvn deploy -s templates/ci_settings.xml
```

Comment: Can I also only clone one specific file? I would have to prevent checking out all files.

Comment: you could try a partial clone: https://github.blog/2020-12-21-get-up-to-speed-with-partial-clone-and-shallow-clone/

Comment: I get the following error: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@/cloudlab.us.oracle.com/cloud-reliability-services/monitoring/common.git/': Could not resolve host: ; Unknown error